# Rolling Text Link

Tags: css, hyperlink, anchor, rollover

I'm using the code found [**here**](http://www.webcreatorbox.com/en/tutorials/css3-text-link/#css3-10) to create my text links located on [**this**](http://brandingbyinsight.com/) page. What I am trying to accomplish is having the rollover text be the description of the link ie: 'Insight' goes to the 'About' page. Some of descriptions are too long and are getting cut off and when I try to make them bigger they just overlap the link next to it. Any suggestions on how to fix it or a better method I should be using? Here is the HTML I'm using.

`<a href="http://brandingbyinsight.com/ingenuity" class="rollover_a" style="color:#000000;"><span data-title="Services">Ingenuity.</span></a>`

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question, not an external resource. Please do not link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking for design advice as well.

[image: Your website]

Judging by the way you have your links presented (each list item with an equal fixed width in a row), a longer description will certainly overlap other links if you do end up finding a solution to make them not "cut off" (it exists, but I'm just not sure if it'll give you a desired result that you're looking for).

Either customize the widths of each list item so they don't overlap, or use some other cool transition (i.e. have the description slide down under the link rather than flip it). That's what I would suggest personally; however, it's up to you to choose what's considered a "better method" of displaying your descriptions.